# JavaFX Dialogue - game

Tags: java, javafx, game-engine

I am currently working on a java game which is supported by a javafx ui.

The player. Should be able to talk to a npc which is no problem. But I want a certain texteffect. Like in the polemon games or undertale where the text appears slowly letter for letter.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Label label = /* the label */ ;
String text = /* text to display */;

IntegerProperty lettersDisplayed = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringProperty(
    () -> text.substring(0, lettersDisplayed.get()),
    lettersDisplayed);

Timeline textAnimation = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(lettersDisplayed, text.length()))
);
```

Comment: i ended up doing this:

Comment: Timeline fiveSecondsWonder2 = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.05), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

   public void handle(ActionEvent event) { 
     textMessage.setText(one.substring(0, i));;
     i++;
   }
  }));
  fiveSecondsWonder2.setCycleCount(one.length());
  fiveSecondsWonder2.play();
 }